# Obtener valores de las propiedades css

Tags: php, html, jquery, color

Quisiera saber como puedo obtener valores de los estilos css, por ejemplo el color.

```
<style>
   .vermellet{color:red;}
</style>

<script>
  //.vermellet{color:red;}
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<a href='www.google.com'>google</a>");
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <p class="vermellet">Hola</p>
  <p>Adios</p>
  <p>Buenos dias</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como veo que estás usando `JQuery`, puedes hacer referencia al elemento con dicha clase y de esta manera obtener el valor de su color mediante la función **[`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**.

Además veo un error de sintaxis en tu código y te falta cerrar la función `$(document).ready(function() {` con un `});`.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").append("<a href='www.google.com'>google</a>");
  
  //Obtenemos el valor del color del elemento cuya clase es `vermellet`
  console.log($(".vermellet").css("color"));
});
```

```css
.vermellet{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="vermellet">Hola</p>
<p>Adios</p>
<p>Buenos dias</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale perfecto, y si quisiera añadir con el append al final de todo lo que hay dentro de una lista no ordenada,con clase de  ?

```
$( "li" ).each(function() { 
alert(this); 
$("body").append("<div> "+this+" </div>");}

<ul class = naranja>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola @Oriol, esto debería ser un comentario sobre mi respuesta o una edición de tu pregunta, pero no una respuesta. De todas formas, no entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres conseguir.

Comment: Ya pero no podia ponerlo como codigo, el codigo, me explico mejor,  tengo una lista no ordenada en la pagina y lo que quiero hacer es simplemente cojer el contenido de la lista y copiarla dentro de un div que creo con jquery  y tambien usando listas no odenadas, usando las etiquetas <ul> y <li>

Comment: Para eso sería bueno que hicieras una nueva pregunta ya que no tiene que ver con la pregunta original (el obtener el color de un elemento). De esta forma, serán dos preguntas separadas y podrán llegar a un mayor número de personas.